# Using JavaScript to open links (absolute URLs only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I'd like links within a website to open as normal when they take you within the website (navigation, internal page linking) but any links to an external source to open in a new window.

Putting target="_blank" in the HTML isn't an option any more as webkit browsers ignore this so I need to use JavaScript.

How would I use JS to open all absolute URLs on a page in a new window and leave all relative URLs as they are? (This is the method I'd use to distinguish the two.)

I guess it'll be an expanded version of:

```
onclick="window.open(''); return false;"
```

But the rest is beyond me…

I'd prefer to avoid using a class or id (in fact, an id wouldn't be possible due to CMS constraints) as I'd prefer to keep the markup as minimal and semantic as possible.

Comment: Instead of forcing links to open in a new window, let the user decide. You'll have more issues with `window.open()` since modern browsers block popups by default.

Comment: I wish I could. I usually do, but my client's client (don't ask!) is adamant. I've already explained why target="_blank" isn't great and that support for it has been dropped. The pop-up thing would make a lot of sense too. Thanks. Is there a way a browser wouldn't treat it as a pop-up? Maybe a different command?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. This is part of web development, being limited by the capabilities of the client's browser. I'd recommend explaining why browsers don't make it easy to show popups (i.e. users hate them) and don't implement it, if possible.

Comment: The pop-up issue will add weight to my argument. Thanks for the nudge : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector filters the external link. By clicking a new window will be opened.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <!-- Here is your site content -->
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('a[href^="http://"]').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_new');
   });
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Further you can use the following snippet:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var domain = 'http://example.com',
        url = $(this).attr('href'),
        target = '_top';
    if (this.href.indexOf(domain) !== 0) {
        target = '_new';
    }
    window.open(url, target);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darius. How would I work that onto my page? Just inside some <script> tags in the head?

Comment: I edited my first comment. Thats the basic form to use jQuery.

Comment: I've done that and it's not taking. I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 but that can't be it, can it? Here's the page so you can have a look at my source: http://tempertemper.net/portfolio.php

Comment: Okay, that's the problem. jQuery 1.6.2 doesn't support the 'on' method. So you have to type that: $('a[href^="http://"]').click( function(event){ ... I hope, that jQuery 1.6.2 supports that kind of selector. Test it.

Comment: Thanks Darius- I updated jQuery and it's liking it! So if it's an internal link (either relative URL or with an absolute URL beginning with the same website's address) it doesn't open the link in a new window. If it's an external link it does! Brilliant! Thanks for your help : )

Comment: Garr- just tried again and I was wrong. It doesn't open links with the same URL in the same window. I know that wasn't part of the question, but the chap below mentioned that might be an approach and I think he's right. Both would be good as a catch-all as the client has control over the linking via the CMS and may do either. Do you know how I'd add that functionality into the code you've written? Thanks and sorry to be a pain : \

Comment: I hope, that I understand you right, because english isn'n my native language. I edited my comment.

Comment: It's doing the opposite- I'd like external links (links without http://example.com or a relative URL) to open in a new window.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var domain = "http://example.com";
$("a").onclick(function () {
    if (this.href.indexOf(domain) !== 0) {
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

It will attach an onclick handler to all `<a>` on the page. If the link looks like it's pointing to an external site: open a new windows instead and cancel the default click event (`return false`), if not, carry on (`return true`)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm having trouble getting it to work. Do I need to wrap it in a $(document).ready(function() {    }); or something similar? I've placed it at the head of this page http://tempertemper.net/portfolio.php in case it's easier for you to see the code.

Comment: Yes. The code will run in-time at the top of the page you have no `<a>` yet, wrapping it in a `$(document).ready` will postpone execution until all the content has been loaded. If more content is loaded after the `$(document).ready` event, you'll need to apply this function again.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me…! At the moment the script isn't working on my page. This is what I've put in the <head> `<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var domain = "http://tempertemper.net";
$("a").onclick(function () {
    if (this.href.indexOf(domain) !== 0) {
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
});
</script>`